# Problem with creating getters and setters with List

Tags: java, hibernate

Im learning one to many mapping and this is my field for courses

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instructor", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, 
 CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
 private List<Course> courses;
```

I have some other fields, i will update question if someone request but i think other fields and code is not important because everything is okey.

My problem is, when I go to auto generate getters and setters im getting this:

```
 public List<com.hibernate.demo.entity.Course> getCourses() {
    return courses;
 }
```

As you can see for some reason, parameter for list is full package path with name of List field parameter. I can manually change it to just `Course` but that doesnt work after when I try to create this method.

```
public void add(Course tempCourse) {

    if (courses == null) {
        courses = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    courses.add(tempCourse);
    }
```

After manually change List parameter to `Course` my error for method is `Cannot access com.hibernate.demo.entity.Course` so that mean he is still searching for full package even I put parameter to `Course`. Error is on `course.add(tempCourse);`

Also, I created same List in Course class with Instructor paramter and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if the root of your dirs are included in the classpath, and if you Course class is public, if the problem persist show how your classes are structured in the packages, and I know it is a bit silly question, but you imported the class, before generate the getter and setter?

Comment: I have 3 packages: `com.hibernate.demo` ; `com.hibernate.demo.entity` ; `com.hibernate.test.jdb`... Course, Instructor is in `...entity`

Comment: i see, please update your question with the class full code, after auto gen the getters and setters.